# Cells with Declarative_Authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, declarative-authorization, rails-cells

using the gems cells and declarative_authorization (along with Devise) and I'm trying to figure out how to include the permitted_to? into the cell templates. So far I've added this to my cells Cell (the Devise one works for it's helpers):

```
class SidebarCell < Cell::Rails
    include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
    helper_method :current_user
    include Authorization::AuthorizationHelper
    helper_method :permitted_to?



  def display(args)
    @object = args[:object]
    @notice = args[:notice]
    @alert = args[:alert]
    render
  end

end
```

But it's bombing at the fact that declarative_auth helper module uses the following code:

```
def permitted_to? (privilege, object_or_sym = nil, options = {}, &block)
      controller.permitted_to?(privilege, object_or_sym, options, &block)
    end
```

and obviously this gives

```
undefined local variable or method `controller' for ...
```

UPDATE:

After some more thinking, I'm not sure this would ever work with Cells. Declarative_auth needs the controller to base it's rules on, but Cells has nothing to do with that controller. It would seem to me that the two are incompatible, unless I pass a reference to the controller into Cells? Starting to think that Cells isn't the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if you add

```
helper_method :controller
```

that just delegates:

```
def controller
  parent_controller
end
```

Sorry for that inconvenience, but the entire helper architecture in Rails sucks: http://nicksda.apotomo.de/2011/10/rails-misapprehensions-helpers-are-shit/